# AngularJS how to pass a variable in directive and keep the changes (like ngModel)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating components in AngularJS to make more easier the form creation/modification.

The directive is like this:

```
<text-input label="CPF" required="true" disabled="false" mask="NNN.NNN" model="comp.string1">
```

And de JS code:

```
function input () {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            label: '=bind',
            required: '=',
            mask: '=',
            model: '=',
            disabled: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/components/input/input.html',
        controller: 'input-controller',
        controllerAs: 'input'
    };

    return directive;
}
```

I need the "model" attribute be like ng-model, all the changes on the directive scope change this variable on the native scope.

Comment: What you describe is the very purpose of an ngModel...why you not using it?

Comment: Are you saying its not working then? Using '=' should be giving you two way binding between the directive and parent scope.

Comment: I guess that you are not registering the directive as well.
Because it seems ready to go.
Are you sure the directive loaded?

Comment: @Vizkos im creating a components, por example, the input with title and mask, because i will use alot in the form.

Comment: @mindparse was right, the prob is I was not using the same variable ref., I changed and now its working